# Where is the guideline saying it's OK to downvote a hard to answer a question, even if the question in itself is clear

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I got a -1 even when the question was clear, and I stated what I am doing. I got a -1 and a comment stating that it's difficult to answer the question, where I only wanted to learn the syntax and not the logic. It was irrelevant what I am trying to achieve, making logical explanation of the final result unnecessary.

e.g.

[Cannot place WHERE clause while using SQL subquery. Need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50206085/cannot-place-where-clause-while-using-sql-subquery-need)

Comment: Welcome to Meta Stack Exchange! Please note that questions about specific posts are considered off-topic for this site. Please post your question on the per-site meta of the site your question is on, which in this case is [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Difficult questions should never be downvoted for being difficult. Usually they gots of upvotes! If you're getting downvotes it's usually because you haven't explained it well enough, or it looks like it's too easy of a question (ie, people think you're being lazy for asking instead of looking up docs.)

Comment: The comment is not saying "I would have trouble pulling together the necessary knowledge to answer this"; it's saying "this question is ill-defined and therefore a coherent answer is likely to be just guesswork". (This might still be an incorrect judgement of the question, but it's a very different one from "oh I don't know the answer, -1".)

Comment: All that said, you've given me some interesting insight into a distressing phenomenon where lots of new users somehow get the idea that experienced users routinely close- or down-vote questions *just because they don't personally know the answer*.

Comment: I'm 'voting' to leave this question open as the (lack of an) MCVE is a Stack Overflow-centered concept, but it surfaces on some other sites of the network as well. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308227/295232

Comment: @Glorfindel: While I would absolutely agree that the general nature of this kind of "unclearness" is shared across multiple sites, the specific details of this post are very SO-specific, so we can at best just say "well it might be unclear and here's what that would mean, but you're going to have to resolve it on SO in comments or on meta to know for sure".

Comment: It's not "hard to answer" because it's complicated or something, it's "hard to answer" because you seem confused by things like default column types and basic SQL knowledge. Telling us what it is you are trying to do is quite possibly the most useful thing you could say.

Comment: The latest version is much better. Your title has a dangling ". Need" on the end of it which doesn't make any sense and probably has gotten you much more attention than normal, which isn't good when your question has issues. Also, "I tried putting it after the end of ')' of subquery and a couple of other places but always error out." If you mention an error, you should always include that error in the question.

Answer (score 7):

It's hard to answer the question ... **in its current state**. Many of the technical sites in the network require something akin to an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)); Stack Overflow is one of them but [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com) sees this kind of SQL questions as well. Questions which do not have this MCVE are often 'unclear' to the general public (despite the fact that it might be clear to *you*), and 'unclear' is one of the reasons mentioned in the downvote button tooltip:

[image]

Something that might help here is an online testing tool. There are several of them mentioned at the bottom of the [SQL tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info):

> #### Online Testing
>
> While you should always provide [complete code examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (e.g., schema, data sample and expected result) in your question or answer, you can also isolate problematic code and reproduce it in an online environment:
>
> - [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) MySQL 5.6, Oracle 11g R2, PostgreSQL 9.6, PostgreSQL 9.3, SQLite (WebSQL), SQLite (SQL.js), SQL Server 2014
> - Rextester: [SQL Server](http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler), [PostgreSQL](http://rextester.com/l/postgresql_online_compiler), [MySql](http://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler), [Oracle](http://rextester.com/l/oracle_online_compiler)
> - [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) Microsoft SQL Server 2016
> - [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) MySQL 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 8.0 PostgreSQL 9.4, 9.5, 9.6 SQLite 3.16, 3.17, 3.18
> - [db <> fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/) MariaDB 10.2 RC, Oracle 11.2, Postgres 8.4, 9.4, 9.5 and 9.6, SQLite 3.8, SQL Server 2014, 2016 and vNext

but be sure to include all necessary information in the post itself as well; external links should only support what you've written and not be an essential part. The online testing tool will surely help you to construct an MCVE.