# Am I not allowed to answer a post that is badly written?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

Here I answered a question, but before doing so, I did provide anonymous feedback, from review, that the question needs improvement, but I got two downvotes, not because of the answer, so am I not allowed to answer this type of question?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can answer bad questions and you did, nothing stopped you. However, given the very low quality of the question,. you are encouraged to get the asker of the question to improve their question before  answering for them. SE is about high quality questions, if you give these very low effort questions answers, it encourages more bad question in the future.

Comment: This question pertains to a specific site, and should have been asked on the site meta. Where it would also be downvoted, if not closed as a duplicate of the EOQS post.

Comment: @MarkKirby" you are encouraged to get the asker of the question to improve their question before answering for them" I did with feedback

Comment: As Mark said, you can if you want. However, some users might not like that and downvote your answer (can't really blame them in most cases) and more importantly, if the question is indeed off-topic, it'll most likely get deleted (along with your answer) and you will have wasted your time writing that answer. That's why you should try to stick to answering on-topic, useful questions.

Comment: OK, then you did right but you still answerd the low quality question, ideally you should of waited for the post to be improved (never happened) or edited it to be better. I can't speak for the Maths site but answering poor questions seems very frouned upon there. and always attracts downvotes. As this question is about one sites policy on this you might get a better answer at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/ as they can explain in greater detail.

Comment: *"anonymous feedback, from review"* is probably *"Share feedback"* from the "[First questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions)" review queue (*"[choose from the canned responses if the post has the potential of being a good question but cannot be improved by anyone but the post-author.](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/review-first-questions)"*)

Comment: @P.Mort _'is probably "Share feedback" from the "First questions" review queue'_ [Indeed](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/1652371) :)

Comment: Math SE is a bit different from other sites it is strictly not allowed to answer contextless question as per [this policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/876009)

Comment: I'm voting to leave this open; the problem originated on a single site but might apply to others as well, and it can be answered without site-specific knowledge. Cf. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308227/295232

Answer (score 15):

You answer it at your own risk - and encourage behaviours that could hurt the OP in the long run

You encourage the user to ask poor questions (rather than trying to educate them to do better), and a pattern of this might lead to a question ban

Your answer might get invalidated if OP changes his question substantially, and you'll get downvoted for either of the above.There might be votes on the answer on its own merit in either way.

If you want to be helpful, and you should be, you should comment asking the user for clarification, try to embed inline the image linked, or better yet transcribe the contents of the image and more or less help the user get their question into shape *first* before trying to answer.

Comment: "(rather than trying to educate them to do better)" for the 4th time , I did with a feedback

Comment: But the question wasn't actually improved before you answered. And one can go further than 'just' the canned review. Consider the next comment, which looks like a more specific comment that tells what the specific issues are, and the last comment, which while terse, spells out the precise issue, which *hasn't been addressed*.

Comment: @islamm: What do mean by *"I did with a feedback"*? By posting a comment? A flag? Something else?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q : you can see I marked it in the first photo

Comment: @JourneymanGeek : it has been addressed when I answered

Comment: @islamm - You answered a question that should have been closed, improved, then reopened making it eligible to be answered.  You failed to even edit the question to inline the screenshot (you have the reputation to do that).  **You simply choose to answer a poorly written question.**

Comment: Another thing that can be added is that Math SE is a bit different from other sites it is strictly not allowed to answer contextless question as per [this policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/876009)